# How can i convert my dataset into json format like my required format

Tags: pandas

i want to convert my this dataset 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvGAN.png)

into this json format using pandas

```
y = {'name':['a','b','c'],"rollno":[1,2,3],"teacher":'xyz',"year":1998}
```

Answer (score 0):

First create dictionary by [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) and filter out duplicated lists for scalars in dictionary comprehension with `if-else` by check length of sets:

```
d = {k:v if len(set(v)) > 1 else v[0] for k, v in df.to_dict('l').items()}
print (d)
{'name': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'rollno': [1, 2, 3], 'teacher': 'xyz', 'year': 1998}
```

And then convert to json:

```
import json

j = json.dumps(d)
print (j)
{"name": ["a", "b", "c"], "rollno": [1, 2, 3], "teacher": "xyz", "year": 1998}
```

If values should be duplicated:

```
import json

j = json.dumps(df.to_dict(orient='l'))
print (j)
{"name": ["a", "b", "c"], "rollno": [1, 2, 3], 
 "teacher": ["xyz", "xyz", "xyz"], "year": [1998, 1998, 1998]}
```